# Jenkins to call powershell script but doesn't execute

Tags: powershell, jenkins

Is there a way wherein Jenkins call a powershell script and just stops without waiting for an output? I don't want it to run under the context of jenkins. Jenkins would be used ONLY to pass the form parameters.

**Reason** : Jenkins doesn't work quite well with Internet explorer COM objects because script works fine when called directly or task scheduler but fails using Jenkins at few steps. Tried multiple work-around but failed.

So, the resolution is that I would call the script using Jenkins only so that it runs under the context of powershell only. Jenkins would be used **ONLY to pass the form parameters**.

Regards,

Rahul

Comment: There is a simple way to do this if I understood correctly. Kindly go throught [THIS](https://www.tothenew.com/blog/running-powershell-scripts-using-jenkins/)

Comment: It's the COM objects running issue and not just running a powershell code using Jenkins. Thanks anyways. :-)

Comment: Which is that COM?

Comment: Internet Explorer object.

Answer (score 0):

powershell `Start-Job` command should work

```
powershell script: '''
Start-Job {
   param($someArgument)
   // set location as current directory
   Set-Location $using:PWD
   //start a command
   PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command .\myscript.ps1
} -Name "myJob1" -ArgumentList $someArgument
'''
```

Comment: This shows an error  -
-Command "&\"./myscript.ps1\""

Error : Missing property name after reference operator.

Comment: fixed, &" " syntax is to execute a executable, no need for a script

Comment: Didn't server the purpose as Jenkins is still using it's powershell plugin to run due to which the script is failing.